# How can I get query of MYSQL table with string column value, where it is "01" to a certain 1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This doesn't look working

```
Mytable.where("property::int = ? ",
               params[:property].to_i)
```

I need a query to find `002` or `02` for 2 for example

Comment: Seems like it should be a numeric column to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MySQL's LIKE operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like).

```
property = params[:property].to_i
Mytable.where("property LIKE ?", "%#{property}")
```

Comment: For `property=2`, it will find record with value `123`

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I edited my answer. The requirements are quite vague, so I don't know if it's only 02, or 002 or XX2.

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't forget to index the property column in your table.

Also you are not much clear in the question. The column will have the data in form of "002" / "02" / "2" OR it can be "123"/"213" format as well?

If its just "002" / "02" / "2" format, then you can do it as below:

```
Mytable.where("property LIKE ?", "%#{params[:property].to_i}")
```

Or if you assume all the formats including "123"/"213", then:

```
Mytable.where("property LIKE ?", "%#{params[:property].to_i}%")
```

Also you may want to check the `params[:property]` parameter value to be present, numericality etc.